# How can I register a component in <script setup>?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How can I register a component in `<script setup>`?

[image: img]

Comment: Isn't that in the documentation? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: OP is using <script SETUP> (Vue 3) not <script>

Answer (score 4):

**Updated answer:**

During the alpha stages of `<script setup>`'s implementation, component registration was done by exporting the component definition.

With the current officially released version (3.2.x), importing the component definition as you've done correctly registers the component:

```html
<script setup>
import HiButton from '@/components/hive/button/index.vue' ✅
</script>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-component-registration?file=src%2FApp.vue)

---

*Old answer that worked for alpha version of `<script setup>` in 30-SEP-2020:*

<del>According to the [RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/sfc-improvements/active-rfcs/0000-sfc-script-setup.md#exposing-components), your `<script setup>` block needs to export the component like this:</del>

```
<script setup>
export { default as HiButton } from '@/components/hive/button/index.vue'
</script>
```

[<del>demo 2</del>](https://codesandbox.io/s/exposing-vue-components-in-script-setup-b2s9d?file=/src/App.vue)